# xml to json conversion using AtlasMap

Tags: java, json, xml, apache-camel, atlasmap

While exploring the efficient conversion tool for xml to json, I find AtlasMap! (https://atlasmap.io) is a very useful.
AtlasMap standalone application helps to formulate source to target mapping file.  It supports transforming data to and from XML, JSON and Java objects.
Most important thing, my project is heavily Apache camel depended and it supports camel component too.

Though it is working fine for small payload, it is giving very bad performance for large payload for xml to json conversion.
I believe it is using DOM parser for xml processing, if so how can I configure STAX or Woodstox parser? Or what to do for large xml to json conversion if I want to use AtlasMap? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in AtlasMap. Unfortunately we haven't supported stream processing for XML/JSON yet, but it's definitely on the table. If you could file an issue on our GitHub repo and attracts other people's vote, it helps to be prioritized.

https://github.com/atlasmap/atlasmap

cf. https://github.com/atlasmap/atlasmap/issues/45

Comment: great to hear from you. I will follow your suggestions to make it prioritized.